# Embedded Kafka starting with wrong number of partitions

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-kafka-test

I have started an instance of EmbeddedKafka in a JUnit test. I can read the records that I have pushed to my stream correctly in my application, but one thing I have noticed is that I only have one partition per topic. Can anyone explain why?

In my application I have the following:

```
List<PartitionInfo> partitionInfos = consumer.partitionsFor(topic);
```

This returns a list with one item. When running against local Kafka with 3 partitions, it returns a list with 3 items as expected.

And my test looks like:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@EmbeddedKafka(partitions = 3)
@ActiveProfiles("inmemory")
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@TestPropertySource(
                locations = "classpath:application-test.properties",
                properties = {"app.onlyMonitorIfDataUpdated=true"})
public class MonitorRestKafkaIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private EmbeddedKafkaBroker embeddedKafkaBroker;

    @Value("${spring.embedded.kafka.brokers}")
    private String embeddedBrokers;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    @Autowired
    private JsonUtility jsonUtility;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
            mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(wac).build();
            UserGroupInformation.setLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.createRemoteUser("dummyUser"));
    }

        private ResultActions interactiveMonitoringREST(String eggID, String monitoringParams) throws Exception {
            return mockMvc.perform(post(String.format("/eggs/%s/interactive", eggID)).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE).content(monitoringParams));
        }

        @Test
        @WithMockUser("super_user")
        public void testEmbeddedKafka() throws Exception {
            Producer<String, String> producer = getKafkaProducer();
            sendRecords(producer, 3);

            updateConn();

            interactiveMonitoringREST(EGG_KAFKA, monitoringParams)
                    .andExpect(status().isOk())
                    .andDo(print())
                    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.taskResults[0].resultDetails.numberOfRecordsProcessed").value(3))
                    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.taskResults[0].resultDetails.numberOfRecordsSkipped").value(0));
        }

        private void sendRecords(Producer<String, String> producer, int records) {
            for (int i = 0; i < records; i++) {
                String val = "{\"auto_age\":" + String.valueOf(i + 10) + "}";
                producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(testTopic, String.valueOf(i), val));
            }
            producer.flush();
        }

        private Producer<String, String> getKafkaProducer() {
            Map<String, Object> prodConfigs = new HashMap<>(KafkaTestUtils.producerProps(embeddedKafkaBroker));
            return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(prodConfigs, new StringSerializer(), new StringSerializer()).createProducer();
        }

        private void updateConn() throws Exception {
            String conn = getConnectionREST(CONN_KAFKA).andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString();
            ConnectionDetail connectionDetail = jsonUtility.fromJson(conn, ConnectionDetail.class);
            connectionDetail.getDetails().put(ConnectionDetailConstants.CONNECTION_SERVER, embeddedBrokers);
            String updatedConn = jsonUtility.toJson(connectionDetail);
            updateConnectionREST(CONN_KAFKA, updatedConn).andExpect(status().isOk());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell the broker to pre-create the topics...

```java
@SpringBootTest
@EmbeddedKafka(topics = "foo", partitions = 3)
class So57481979ApplicationTests {

    @Test
    void testPartitions(@Autowired KafkaAdmin admin) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        AdminClient client = AdminClient.create(admin.getConfig());
        Map<String, TopicDescription> map = client.describeTopics(Collections.singletonList("foo")).all().get();
        System.out.println(map.values().iterator().next().partitions().size());
    }

}
```

Or set the `num.partitions` broker property if you want the broker to auto-create the topics for you on first use.

We should probably automatically do that, based on the partitions property.

Answer (score 0):

I found `bootstrapServersProperty` is important in `@EmbeddedKafka`, which is used to populate the property in the `application-test.yml`, which then can be used to create consumers/listener containers.