# Multiple kafka Consumer Not receiving messages

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I am using embeddedKafkaBroker and Kafka Binder Streams.

```
@Configuration
@Profile({"dev", "test"})
@Slf4j
public class EmbeddedKafkaBrokerConfig {

  private static final String TMP_EMBEDDED_KAFKA_LOGS =
      String.format("/tmp/embedded-kafka-logs-%1$s/", UUID.randomUUID());
  private static final String PORT = "port";
  private static final String LOG_DIRS = "log.dirs";
  private static final String LISTENERS = "listeners";
  private static final Integer KAFKA_PORT = 9092;
  private static final String LISTENERS_VALUE = "PLAINTEXT://localhost:" + KAFKA_PORT;
  private static final Integer ZOOKEEPER_PORT = 2181;

  private EmbeddedKafkaBroker embeddedKafkaBroker;

  /**
   * bean for the embeddedKafkaBroker.
   *
   * @return local embeddedKafkaBroker
   */
  @Bean
  @Qualifier("embeddedKafkaBroker")
  public EmbeddedKafkaBroker embeddedKafkaBroker() {
    Map<String, String> brokerProperties = new HashMap<>();
    brokerProperties.put(LISTENERS, LISTENERS_VALUE);
    brokerProperties.put(PORT, KAFKA_PORT.toString());
    brokerProperties.put(LOG_DIRS, TMP_EMBEDDED_KAFKA_LOGS);
    this.embeddedKafkaBroker =
        new EmbeddedKafkaBroker(1, true, 2)
            .kafkaPorts(KAFKA_PORT)
            .zkPort(ZOOKEEPER_PORT)
            .brokerProperties(brokerProperties);
    return embeddedKafkaBroker;
  }

  /** close the embeddedKafkaBroker on destroy. */
  @PreDestroy
  public void preDestroy() {
    if (embeddedKafkaBroker != null) {
      log.warn("[EmbeddedKafkaBrokerConfig]  destroying kafka broker {}", embeddedKafkaBroker);
      embeddedKafkaBroker.destroy();
    }
  }
}
```

Using Rest Controller to trigger publish data to the topic

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1/demo/")
public class DemoController {

  @Autowired
  DemoSupplier demoSupplier;

  @GetMapping("hello")
  public String helloController(){
    demoSupplier.supply();
    return "Hello World!";
  }
}
```

DemoSupplier.class

```
@Component
public class DemoSupplier {

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("embeddedKafkaBroker")
  public EmbeddedKafkaBroker kafkaBroker;

  @Autowired
  private KafkaTemplate<String,String> kafkaTemplate;

  @Value("${demo.topic}")
  private String topicName;
  @Bean
  public KafkaTemplate<String, String> stringKafkaTemplate(){
    Map<String, Object> producerConfigs =new HashMap<>();
    producerConfigs.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,"localhost:9092");
    producerConfigs.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    producerConfigs.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,StringSerializer.class);
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfigs));
  }

  public void supply(){
    for(int i =0 ;i<100;i++){
      kafkaTemplate.send(topicName, "Message:"+i*2);
    }
  }
}
```

Consumers

```
@Component
public class DemoConsumer {

  @Bean
  @Qualifier("demoConsumerProcessor")
  public Consumer<KStream<String, String>> demoConsumerProcessor(){
    return input -> input.foreach(((key, value) -> System.out.println(value)));
  }
  @Bean
  @Qualifier("demoConsumerProcessor2")
  public Consumer<KStream<String, String>> demoConsumerProcessor2(){
    return input -> input.foreach(((key, value) -> System.out.println("This is second consumer 2: "+value)));
  }
}
```

Application.properties-

```
# ===============================
# = Profiles
# ===============================
spring.profiles.active=dev
server.port=8181
# ===============================
# = Kafka Topics
# ===============================
demo.topic=demoTopic
object.demo.topic=objectDemoTopic
# ===============================
# = SPRING CLOUD STREAM
# ===============================
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.demoConsumerProcessor-in-0.destination=demoTopic
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.demoConsumerProcessor2-in-0.destination=demoTopic
spring.cloud.stream.function.definition=demoConsumerProcessor,demoConsumerProcessor2
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.functions.demoConsumerProcessor.applicationId=group_id
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.functions.demoConsumerProcessor2.applicationId=group_id
spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
```

Note-
In this property(spring.cloud.stream.function.definition), the name of bean that appears first will consume the message published to the topic. But only one of them receives them. Both consumer have the same group id, according to my knowledge set using applicationId, saw the same in logs also.

**Now here comes my deduction-**

Number of partitions created by embedded Kafka are always 1. I have tried changing it to 2 when I am creating its bean(See constuctor of it- (count:1, controlledShutdownn:true, partitions:2). But i think somethings are not in places.

Important logs-

```
[Consumer clientId=group_id-359878ed-1b41-4cf0-b9b8-6e21e5e1f0fe-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=group_id] Updating assignment with
Assigned partitions:                       [demoTopic-0]
Current owned partitions:                  []
Added partitions (assigned - owned):       [demoTopic-0]
Revoked partitions (owned - assigned):     []
```

---

```
Consumer clientId=group_id-4dce1ba5-7d97-4c18-92c3-cb79dab271b5-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=group_id] Updating assignment with
Assigned partitions:                       []
Current owned partitions:                  []
Added partitions (assigned - owned):       []
Revoked partitions (owned - assigned):     []
```

Now according to logs , maybe only one partition is created for the topic.

Now some confusion is regarding "Updating assignment", is their any more property i have to set to use multiple consumer. Or Some problem with embeddedKafa.
Please look from other perspective dont want to be a XY Problem.
Full logs are too big. I will share if needed.

Comment: By default, only 1 partition is created for topics automatically, yes, but you can use a NewTopic bean to create topics via Spring

Comment: So, your thought game me one idea-
I am asking the broker to create topic while creating its bean-

this.embeddedKafkaBroker =
        new EmbeddedKafkaBroker(1, true, 2,"demoTopic")
            .kafkaPorts(KAFKA_PORT)
            .zkPort(ZOOKEEPER_PORT)
            .brokerProperties(brokerProperties);
    return embeddedKafkaBroker;


Now both consumer receiving the record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution i found is not ideal, but it did the job-

I am asking the broker to create topic while creating its bean-

```
 this.embeddedKafkaBroker = new EmbeddedKafkaBroker(1, true, 2,"demoTopic") 
      .kafkaPorts(KAFKA_PORT) 
      .zkPort(ZOOKEEPER_PORT) 
      .brokerProperties(brokerProperties); 
    return embeddedKafkaBroker;
```

Now both consumer receiving the record.

Comment: Why is this not ideal?

Comment: @OneCricketeer The goal of the question was to explore function args to get the required number of topics. Setting up the topic with the required number of partitions after broker have been started.

Comment: You can create `@Bean NewTopic` functions for this

Comment: What is the best practice according to you? Using embedded Kafka or TestContainers? @OneCricketeer

Comment: I don't have experience with TestContainers. Both should work with `@Bean NewTopic` or using `AdminClient.createTopic` method directly

Answer (score 0):

If there's only one partition, then only one consumer in the same group will be able to process that partition.

Ideally, you create topics yourself rather than letting the broker do it automatically. In fact, it's recommended to disable that setting.

Your other options are to use distinct groups or to call two different processing methods but use one group

```
@Bean
  @Qualifier("demoConsumerProcessor")
  public Consumer<KStream<String, String>> demoConsumerProcessor(){
    return input -> input.foreach(((key, value) -> {
        System.out.println(value);
        System.out.println("second consumer " +  value))) 
    } 
  })) ;
```

Comment: All this makes sense, but whole point of my question was to create multiple consumer in same group for a topic. It might not be making sense why i am creating multiple consumer, but its a requirement for me. Stackoverflow is strange place, some says you should do things automatically, some deny that. Pls see- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57481979/embedded-kafka-starting-with-wrong-number-of-partitions

Comment: `topics = "foo", partitions = 3` in the annotation is exactly what I said to do. Not pass a constructor parameter for default partition size

Comment: I have already tried that, thats not working.